Center of braid group $B_3$
I have been trying to properly prove the center of $B_3:= \{\sigma_1,\sigma_2 \mid \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma _1= \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2  \}$ is $ \langle(\sigma_1 \sigma_2)^3\rangle$. I defined the morphism $\phi: B_3 \to PSL_2 (\mathbb{Z})=\langle v,w\mid v^2,w^3\rangle$ by $\phi(\sigma_1)=w^{-1}v$ and $\phi(\sigma_2)=v^{-1}w^2$. The only thing to prove for me that I can't properly formalize is that $\ker\phi= \langle(\sigma_1 \sigma_2)^3\rangle$ because then I can conclude the center is equal to $\langle(\sigma_1 \sigma_2)^3\rangle$ because the center of the modular group is trivial. Anybody that can help properly prove this about the kernel?

my apologies for this, I made my representation of $B_3$ clear now.

Is $\phi$ surjective?   Not sure how you argue about the center.

Using Tietze transformations on the presentation, define
$$x=\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1,\  y=\sigma_1\sigma_2,$$
and then eliminate
$$\sigma_1=y^{-1}x,\ \sigma_2=\sigma_1^{-1}x\sigma_1^{-1}= x^{-1}y^2,$$
and the presentation becomes
$$\langle x,y \mid x=x^{-1}y^3\rangle = \langle x,y \mid x^2 = y^{3}\rangle.$$
In this form, it is clear that $y^3 \in Z(B_3)$, and
$$B_3/\langle y^3 \rangle \cong \langle v,w \mid v^2=w^2=1 \rangle.$$
As a free product of non-trivial groups, this right hand group has trivial centre, so $Z(B_3) = \langle y^3 \rangle = \langle (\sigma_1\sigma_2)^3 \rangle$.

Thanks a lot, what I needed!
